# Getting error when running apt-get -f install

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg, dependencies

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
Setting up tzdata (2014e-0ubuntu0.13.10) ...
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing tzdata (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tzdata
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try this command : sudo apt-get install debconf --reinstall

Comment: Doesn't work :( same error again & again

Answer (score 0):

Run :

```
sudo dpkg -r tzdata
```

If it is successful or not, then run:

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the resulting Gedit remove the whole section starts with:

`Package : tzdata`

save the file and close.

Then run your command.